# Combine character columns into new column

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, concatenation

I'd be very grateful if you could help me with the following as after a few tests I haven't still been able to get the right outcome.

I've got this data:

```
dd_1 <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5"),
                 Class_a = c("a",NA, "a", NA, NA),
                 Class_b = c(NA, "b", "b", "b", "b"))
```

And I'd like to produce a new column 'CLASS':

```
dd_2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5"),
                 Class_a = c("a",NA, "a", NA, NA),
                 Class_b = c(NA, "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                 CLASS = c("a", "b", "a-b", "b", "b"))
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
tmp <- paste(dd_1$Class_a, dd_1$Class_b, sep='-')
tmp <- gsub('NA-|-NA', '', tmp)
(dd_2 <- cbind(dd_1, tmp))
```

First we concatenate (join as strings) the 2 columns. `paste` treats `NA`s as ordinary strings, i.e. `"NA"`, so we either get `NA-a`, `NA-b`, or `a-b`. Then we substitute `NA-` or `-NA` with an empty string.

Which results in:

```
##   ID Class_a Class_b tmp
## 1  1       a    <NA>   a
## 2  2    <NA>       b   b
## 3  3       a       b a-b
## 4  4    <NA>       b   b
## 5  5    <NA>       b   b
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
dd_1$CLASS <- with(dd_1, ifelse(is.na(Class_a), as.character(Class_b),
                               ifelse(is.na(Class_b), as.character(Class_a), 
                                        paste(Class_a, Class_b, sep="-"))))
```

This way you would check if any of the classes is NA and return the other, or, if none is NA, return both separated by "-".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution with `apply`:

```
dd_2 <- cbind(dd_1, CLASS = apply(dd_1[2:3], 1, 
                                  function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = "-")))
```

The result

```
  ID Class_a Class_b CLASS
1  1       a    <NA>     a
2  2    <NA>       b     b
3  3       a       b   a-b
4  4    <NA>       b     b
5  5    <NA>       b     b
```